# What's on a Kazon's Head?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I've been watching a lot of *Star Trek: Voyager* recently and it's reminded me of a question I had when I watched it the first time around.

[image: Headshot of a Kazon looking disgusted; it showcases their "hair" - a bushy, feathery type thing]

All Kazon have a kind of feathery thing instead of hair. What exactly is this? Are they feathers? Is it some kind of keratin growth like hair or nails? Is it soft to the touch or hard?

In other words - what exactly is that on their heads!?

Comment: [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kazon) refers to it as hair a few times.

Comment: I have always thought that that was a kind of dried mud/clay, which also explained their clay-like skin colour. This will also explain why the Borg didn't want to assimilate them. :)

Comment: I always thought they looked like some kind of milkweed-like pods that they kept in their hair for easy access to water/sustenance.

Comment: I just figured they had really poor sanitation standards and never invented shampoo...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Memory Alpha's entry on the [Kazon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kazon) under physiology it is hair, albeit chunks of hair rather than individual strands:

> The foreheads of all Kazon featured distinctive ridges and their black or brown hair grew in large chunks rather than individual strands.

Answer (score 4):

Reading the creative directors interview, the Kazons hair is made up of sponges and pig ears that are often sold as dog treats. She also said that there were varied opinions about the hair style. Stating some loved the idea and some hated it. They were meant to act as this gens "Klingons" as far as the antagonist but needed to be completely different as far as costume design went.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F Suzanne! The original post is asking an in-universe explanation and thus, your answer cannot be related to it (as you're giving an out-of-universe explanation). Great answer though unfortunately, it will be closed/deleted.

Comment: Don't think there's any need to close / delete / downvote - even though it's an out-of-universe answer, what it's made of does give insight into how it would feel to the touch which is not only useful information but it also partially answers the original question.

Comment: it's a good, informative answer - if not the 'correct' one and exactly what the site is great for. A link to a source would be even better however